# AWS CLI chain commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am trying to launch multiple instances with a template and have them all have a different name. I had thought maybe I could use the run-instances command each time for how many instances I needed and change the name tag for each one and repeat but it only runs the first one each time. Can I chain these together or can I write one command that will do this for me?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

I have tried the following,

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 1}]"
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 2}]"
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 3}]"
```

and...

```
aws ec2 run-instances --count 3\
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 1}]"
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 2}]"
    --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-05ac76780c7f5e513 \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=INSTANCE 3}]"
```

But it only ever starts the first one.

Comment: Are you saying that the first option (separate commands) works okay? You can put it in a script file and execute them with one command.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Your second approach will not do what you expect. It will only apply one template and one set of tags to *ALL* of the instance that are launched.

Instead, you could use the [AMI launch index value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMI-launch-index-examples.html), which is an automatic number assigned as `ami-launch-index`. It will be different for each instance when the instances are launched with `--count`.

You could write a User Data script that extracts this value and then sets the tag the instance. That is, each instance would have a script that sets the tag value on *itself*.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your message. While I can follow what you are saying I must make it clear I am a complete newbie when it comes to using the CLI. How would I go about writing a User Data script? When you say each instance would have a script that sets the tag value on itself, is this within the VM or a script I would run from the CLI? Again, apologies for my ignorance I'm just not familiar with the CLI whatsoever

Comment: You would [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) that would retrieve this metadata value (eg from a shell script it would be ```ami_launch_index=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index` ```). You could then set the tag using [create-tags — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html). This command would also require the Instance ID (available via Instance Metadata) and an IAM Role with permission to set the tag.

Comment: Yes, these activities are not simple for "a complete newbie" to EC2, but what you are wanting to do is not available as an "out of the box" setting. Instead, you could simply run the command three times (as shown in your first example), which is much easier than scripting the automatic allocation of names.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For some further explanation, I work for a medical company who until recently used app stream to provide up to 60 VM's for workshops and remote training around the world but due to unforseen circumstances regarding our software, app stream no longer works. I was tasked with finding a solution and I used the only thing I know which is EC2. At any time I would need to fire up up to 60 virtual machines and I was trying to make it easier for myself to name them all and assign elastic ips automatically. The current setup works perfectly it just takes a bit of work to start

Comment: As it stands I have gotten quite fast at doing this manually but it's the other support workers who can't get the hang of it so the obvious choice is to try and automate everything to benefit everyone. It has taken me some time to get this far with the CLI launching from a template but no amount of Google searching has provided me with what I require so I thought I would reach out here.

Comment: Can they be Windows systems? If so, have you considered using [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces.html)? These are effectively remote Windows desktops and it is relatively easy to reload them with a base image. They provide a better remote desktop experience than Amazon EC2.